# Styled-JSX variables not working

Tags: reactjs, styles, jsx, styled-components

I have installed styled-jsx using `styled-jsx@2.2.6` and am doing something like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default Index class extends Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = { clicked: false}
  }
  render(){
   return(){
    <div>
    <button onClick={() => this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked}}}>Hello</button>
    <style jsx>{`
    button {
     background-color: ${this.state.clicked ? 'red' : 'blue'}
    }
    `}<style>
  }
 }
}
```

No styles what so ever are being applied and I console logged out the clicked state and it is being changed.

Comment: Did you add styled-jsx to your plugins for babel?

Comment: I am using gatsby. It has a `gatsby-plugin-styled-jsx` that goes in the `gatsby-config`. I did not do it in the .babelrc yet though, how would I do that ?

Comment: {
  "plugins": [
    "styled-jsx/babel"
  ]
}

Comment: now im getting error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: In what part of the process is that error coming out, could you post the entire output?

Comment: When I run the app, I just added the config to the .babelrc is all I did and hit save and refreshed my app. and I get that one line in the console.

Comment: Does the console point to a file/line number of anything at all?

Comment: commons.js --> `import _JSXStyle from 'styled-jsx/style';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170723/discussion-between-taylor-austin-and-chris-cousins).

Comment: `export default Index class extends Component {` -> `export default class Index extends Component {`  and `return(){` -> `return {`

Comment: `return(){` -> `return (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working example. You had lot of typo's in there. I assume you are not using appropriate IDE that usually points out at all those issues.

Here's the working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ttfch

Here's your fixed typoless code:

```
class Index extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { clicked: false }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ clicked: !this.state.clicked })}>
          Hello
        </button>
        <style jsx>{`
          button {
            background-color: ${this.state.clicked ? 'red' : 'blue'}
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to add a plugin to the styled-jsx so I can use nesting. I tried doing this in the babelrc:     `["styled-jsx/babel", { "plugins": ["styled-jsx-plugin-postcss"] }]` but I just get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in the console.

Comment: Those are all plugins that are used during build process assuming your code is compliant to JS sytax. In your case it wasnt the case and as I said you had too many typos. You can click on the link provided above and see it working correctly. Its the same code that you have just without syntax error.